# u-boot bootdelay=2 when booting ext4, and bootdelay=0 when booting fat

Tags: embedded, boot-loader, u-boot, yocto

I am running u-boot on a Beaglebone Black custom install, and have modified ./include/configs/am335x_evm.h to set the default bootdelay to 0, which was working well when I was loading my kernel and device tree off of a fat partition.  But I switched partition 1 from fat to ext4, and change the fatload statements in my uEnv.txt to ext4load.  Everything works just as before, except now I'm back to having a 2 second bootdelay.  I don't understand why switching partition types would cause this.

Does anybody know how I can recompile u-boot to set bootdelay back to 0 in the case of me using ext4 boot partition?

---

Alternatively, I suppose I could figure out how to get saveenv working.  Currently it gives:

```
=> saveenv
Saving Environment to FAT... MMC: no card present
** Bad device mmc 0 **
Failed (1)
```

But honestly I'd rather just change the default at compile time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the ARM cross-compiler GCC on your PC.

```
wget -c https://releases.linaro.org/components/toolchain/binaries/6.4-2017.11/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gcc-linaro-6.4.1-2017.11-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf.tar.xz
tar xf gcc-linaro-6.4.1-2017.11-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf.tar.xz
export CC=**/path to**/gcc-linaro-6.4.1-2017.11-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-
```

Make sure you have the correct path.It should be from the root, something like this /home/username/path to gcc-linaro/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-

Test Cross Compiler:

```
${CC}gcc --version
```

You should see this on your terminal if you have the correct path:

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc (Linaro GCC 6.4-2017.11) 6.4.1 20171012
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Download u-boot

```
git clone https://github.com/u-boot/u-boot
cd u-boot/
git checkout v2018.01 -b tmp
```

Get the patches (Needs internet connection)

```
wget -c https://rcn-ee.com/repos/git/u-boot-patches/v2018.01/0001-am335x_evm-uEnv.txt-bootz-n-fixes.patch
wget -c https://rcn-ee.com/repos/git/u-boot-patches/v2018.01/0002-U-Boot-BeagleBone-Cape-Manager.patch
wget -c https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RobertCNelson/Bootloader-Builder/master/patches/v2018.03-rc1/0002-NFM-Production-eeprom-assume-device-is-BeagleBone-Bl.patch
```

Apply patches to u-boot

```
patch -p1 < 0001-am335x_evm-uEnv.txt-bootz-n-fixes.patch
patch -p1 < 0002-U-Boot-BeagleBone-Cape-Manager.patch
patch -p1 < 0002-NFM-Production-eeprom-assume-device-is-BeagleBone-Bl.patch
```

Configure and Build

```
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=${CC} distclean
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=${CC} am335x_evm_defconfig
```

Now in the u-boot folder there will be .config file you can edit and change the bootdelay parameter.
Build

```
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=${CC}
```

Attach the SD card to the computer and run ‘lsblk’ to find out the id of the SD card. In my case the id was ‘sdb’

Install:

```
export DISK=/dev/sdb
sudo dd if=./MLO of=${DISK} count=1 seek=1 bs=128k
sudo dd if=./u-boot.img of=${DISK} count=2 seek=1 bs=384k
```

Comment: So I just saw your answer and haven't tried this yet, but I'm marking it answered because it hit on part of what was going wrong with my install.

Comment: Someone else noticed that if you zero the eMMC first before installing my system, the system fails to boot.  I figured out that's because the old MLO and u-boot.img were still in that 1M space before the first partition, and that's what the BBB was using since it couldn't find a fat partition.  So my system was actually only booting at all by accident.

Comment: I actually switched back to fat to make it work, but I might use this solution where I put the MLO and u-boot.img in the space before the first partition instead.  Thanks!